# Default Pattern MVC on Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I think I read somewhere that by default all Android applications were based on the MVC pattern, are that true?

Could I have information that affirm or deny these statements.

Thank you all.

Comment: Where did you read it?

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the link, but is it wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are that true?

No.

> Could I have information that affirm or deny these statements

Android's view framework was not designed around any particular architecture. You are welcome to attempt to make your Android app adopt MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc., but none are an exact match.

Comment: Thank you for blessing me with your knowledge ^^

Answer (score 1):

Explanation by Realm here:

https://news.realm.io/news/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/ shows that by Default Android studio's project are in MVC architecture.
Also, this blog gives a brief idea of the difference between MVC.MVP, MVVM.

I have a repo on GitHub with same Chat application using firebase written in MVC, MVP, MVVM shows how same Application can be written in all three formats.

https://github.com/saksham24/Android-Firebase-Mvp-Mvc-Mvvm-chat